# How to have colors based PolyLine with folium (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, folium

I have a dataset which is composed by the following columns: latitude, longitude, value.

I want to draw a polyline in folium, with these three colours, based on the value:

- 75 < value < 85 : yellow
- 85 < value < 95 : orange
- value > 95 : red

Since one "value" is associated to each row containing one latitude and one longitude, I want to calculate the mean of the "value" for each couple of coordinates (so one mean value every two rows), so the colour will be based on that mean value.

How can I do it?

Comment: if your data columns were Numpy arrays, `mean = (value[:-1]+value[+1:])/2; color = np.where(mean>95, 'red', np.where(mean>85, 'orange', 'yellow'))` — no idea about what to do with Folium.

Comment: Please provide some data and what you've tried so far